# How do you perform an inner join using the sas HASH object

Tags: hash, sas, inner-join

As I understand this is a left join:

```
data deb;
if 0 then set ids DMREPORT;
if _n_=1 then do;
ds="DMREPORT";
        declare Hash a (dataset:ds, multidata:'Y',hashexp:15); 
     a.DefineKey ('debt_item_reference','system_date');
     a.DefineData (all:'Y'); 
     a.DefineDone (); 
     end;
set ids;
rc=a.find(key:fnum, key:hdat);
do while(rc=0);
output;
rc=a.find_next();
end;
drop ds;
run;
```

How would one perform an inner join,and what about HoH equivalent?

What I tried:

```
data bla;
if 0 then set A B;
If _n_=1 then do;
     declare Hash a (dataset:'A', multidata:'Y',hashexp:15); 
     a.DefineKey ('Key1','Key2');
     a.DefineData (all:'Y'); 
     a.DefineDone (); 
    
     declare Hash b (dataset:'B', multidata:'Y',hashexp:15); 
     b.DefineKey ('key1','key2');
     b.DefineData (all:'Y'); 
     b.DefineDone (); 
     end;

rc=a.find();
rb=b.find();
do while(rc=0 and rb=0)
output;
rc=a.find_next();
rb=b.find_next();
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inner join vs. left join is simply a matter of whether you keep the "source" dataset rows that don't have a match.

Terminology: "Source" dataset = left dataset, "Target" dataset = right dataset.

- Outer join:  Keep all rows from "source" dataset, append any columns from "target" that match, and then append all rows from "Target" that do not match
- Left join: Keep all rows from "source" dataset, append any columns from "Target" that match
- Inner join: Keep only rows from "source" that have matching "target" rows, append columns from "target"

That's a pretty common use case.  In the case of the hash, the `if rc eq 0 then output` is what makes something an inner join - if there is a default `output` then it's a left join.

Inner join:

```
rc = h.find();
if rc eq 0 then output;
```

Left join:

```
rc = h.find();
output;
```

Outer join - first find all the matches, remove them from the match, then iterate over the hash table to find the non-matching rows and output them too:

```
rc = h.find();
output;
rc_r = h.remove();

*eof defined in the set statement (end=eof);
*hi is hiter for h;
if eof then do;
   rc = hi.first();
   do while rc eq 0;
      output;
      rc = hi.next();
   end;
end;
```

You wouldn't use two hash tables the way you have, normally, it makes things way more complicated and slower.

Here's a practical example:

```
data classfit_male;
  set sashelp.classfit;
  if sex='M';
run;

data left_join;
  set sashelp.class;
  if 0 then set classfit_male;
  if _n_ eq 1 then do;
    declare hash h_cf(dataset:'classfit_male');
    h_cf.defineKey('name');
    h_cf.defineData(all:'y');
    h_cf.defineDone();  
  end;
  
  rc_cf = h_cf.find();
  output;
  call missing(of _all_);
run;

data inner_join;
  set sashelp.class;
  if 0 then set classfit_male;
  if _n_ eq 1 then do;
    declare hash h_cf(dataset:'classfit_male');
    h_cf.defineKey('name');
    h_cf.defineData(all:'y');
    h_cf.defineDone();  
  end;
  
  rc_cf = h_cf.find();
  if rc_cf eq 0 then output;
  call missing(of _all_);
run;

data outer_join;
  set sashelp.class(where=(age le 13)) end=eof;
  if 0 then set classfit_male;
  if _n_ eq 1 then do;
    declare hash h_cf(dataset:'classfit_male');
    h_cf.defineKey('name');
    h_cf.defineData(all:'y');
    h_cf.defineDone();  
    declare hiter hi_cf('h_cf');
  end;
  
  rc_cf = h_cf.find();
  output;
  rc_rm = h_cf.remove();
  
  call missing(of _all_);
  if eof then do;
    rc_cf = hi_cf.first();
    do while (rc_cf eq 0);
      output;
      rc_cf = hi_cf.next();
    end;  
  end;  
run;
```

What I wrote above doesn't handle multiple rows per key; the concept doesn't really change then, you just have to add the find_nexts to make that work, though honestly I tend to find that if you have multiple rows per key hash table solutions tend to perform poorer than other alternatives.